# Auto joining using webex

Tags: python, operating-system, bots

I want to join my webex that is installed in my win10.
The prog I made can run the exe . but I can't figure out how to navigate through the API and input the link in the box so that I can join.
My code so far:

```
import os
import time

os.chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Webex\Webex\Applications")
print(os.getcwd())
os.system("ptoneclk.exe")
time.sleep(60)

link="https://wiprocon.webex.com/wiprocon/j.php?MTID=evbkjebvebciwt7efvwjvjwvd"
```

[image]

added a SS of webex interface if that might help.

Any help would do , like you can suggest me some module that I can try incase you don't know thw solution.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are looking for is to automate the interation of Windows application using Python. There are various options out there, but i will mention my favourite

[**pywinauto**](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto)

Also read https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#how-to-know-magic-attribute-names

Then you can:

```
from pywinauto.application import 
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys   
app = Application().start('path/to/ptoneclk.exe', timeout=60)
app.WindowName['Join a Meeting'].set_text(your_meeting_url')
#And finally submit
send_key("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: I think the first line should be `from pywinauto.application import Application` .Correct me if I am wrong. and I cant find any ref. to  `WindowName['No. of loops:Edit']`  online. Please let me know how should that be written.  Btw this module helps .It is amazing!

Comment: Yeah my bad i missed that `from pywinauto.application import Application`

Comment: Could you please tell me what "windowName" do?

Comment: WindowName is a placeholder here, it is the name of your window. To get the particular window name you can run this, `app.windows()`, it will give you list of window names open in your pc. In your case it maybe `CiscoWebex` or something else